# Convert MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, migration, percona-toolkit

What are the considerations needed when converting myisam to innodb.

I have a table around 80 GB with engine myisam. I would like to convert into innodb. What are the considerations needed to convert.

I'm using percona  MySQL. I checked the table indexes and there is no full text searching indexes for the above table.

I plan to use percona online scheme change.

What are the considerations/pre-requisite to keep in mind to do this activity?

Comment: 1) How much free space do you have in datadir right now ? 2) Please post the table structure of the 80GB table. 3) What is the output of`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';` 4) How much RAM in the DB Server ? 5) How many CPU/cores ? 6) Is the DB Server bare metal or VM ?

Comment: 1. Avail space 3.6T.
2. 
mysql> show create table edition.classic\G
       Table: classic
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `classic` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `classic_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `classic_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `classic_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classic_value` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1236398635 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

3.innodb_file_per_table=ON
4.total mem=33gb, no swap
5. CPU(s) core=4 6.Its in amazon virtual.

Comment: Hi @RonaldoMySQLDBA, Do you have time to look my comment please.

Answer (score 4):

1. InnoDB tables tend to occupy more space than MyISAM tables do.
2. While converting, new physical files are being created, so you have to have free space on the disk (Hard to estimate, but to be safe I would say 120G)
3. If you use Percona tools to make the change online, all modifications on the original table will be stored in a temporary table using triggers. So depending on the DML operations,i.e. inserts/updates/deletes, you may need more space. Be careful that on high traffic tables, triggers may affect the performance.
4. It could be that some InnoDB related configuration should be tuned.

If in your setup you have two or more servers, like master-master, or master-slave(s), I think it is better to do it offline, one server at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I have an [*MyISAM2InnoDB blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) that covers your question thoroughly.

It discusses index differences, especially `PRIMARY KEY` and `FULLTEXT`, space (2x-3x is typical), `LOCK TABLES`, decreasing `key_buffer_size` and increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (very important), etc.

Comment: Looks good. Can I use the same for using pt-osc to convert myisam to innodb

Comment: Good point; I added a [_section on pt-osc_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#pt_online_schema_change)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the issue is resolved. But as suggested here're some ways you can do this :
1. ALTER TABLE Approach : 
ALTER TABLE  ENGINE=INNODB;
Considerations for this approach : As you mentioned you have a big table this command will take time to execute.

2. CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO Approach : 
   You can create a empty table with INNODB storage engine and start dumping data from your source table into this. If the data is huge you can do the conditional insert based on your Primary Key. Insert data in chunks.

Here's the few links you should consider looking at before doing this :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/myisam-to-innodb/
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/

Hope this helps!!!